# How to form curved concrete seat for bench with back?

Tags: concrete

The contractor seems very unsure of procedure.  He has put some very thin plastic around the front edge of the curve, holding it in place with wide black plastic tape.  It is about 1.5 inches tall.  The plastic strip looks like something that would be a corner bead for sheet-rock, not for concrete.  It has holes in it. To close the holes, he taped it; and he only taped it after I asked him what would keep the concrete from oozing into the holes and binding that plastic to the concrete so it couldn't be removed easily when the concrete sets.

He says after he puts the concrete in that, he will pour it deeper and put another plastic strip upside down on the edge to give a rounded finish, and smooth it off with a trowel. We want a seat about 3 inches thick, and he says 2.5 inches is enough.

I asked how that concrete is going to stay there without a mold, or bender board, or something, while he is working on it with a trowel, etc.  and he testily replied that it would be fine.

He plans to pour this in the morning.  This question on this site may be too late for us, but may be of interest to others.

Comment: As you've described it, this sounds unconvincing.

Comment: If the contractor is only getting paid after they correctly perform the job, then make sure you are specific about the desired result in any contract and that he's responsible to fix it until it's completed to your specifications. Then let them do their job.

Comment: The contractor poured as described.  After the concrete set, the plastic removed well, until a concrete chunk 14" W x 6" D broke off the middle seat edge. 

Contractor scoured concrete out of an area, 2.5' L x 12"d D.  He blended more concrete into the seat, holding it with bricks, plastic, and hand-shaping the edge.  

The result is rustic, but is set in concrete now.  Also, the seat is only about 2" thick, rather than 3" we wanted; living with it.

We hope the variations of the acid wash, will hide the repair variations.   Pray for us.  :-D